# Enable Edit And Continue missing - VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a new Web API project within Visual Studio 2015. Normally I am able to hit Start Debugging (Play Button), can then "Stop Debugging" and IIS Express keeps running, I can also make code changes in VS, hit Build/Rebuild and have the code take effect (without Start Debugging again). Correct me if I am wrong however I understand that this is made possible by "Edit and Continue".

I use two PCs to work on my project (work PC/laptop) - one date I noticed that when I Stopped Debugging on my Work PC - that IIS Express had stopped. It has now continued to happen on one specific PC, every time I'd Start Debugging, then stop, IIS express would also stop, every time.

I'd not changed anything and Edit and Continue still worked on my laptop.  I also note that I need to ensure that "Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General --> Enable Edit and Continue" needs to be checked, which it is on both my Visual Studio

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas how to get this working again?

I've tried: 
- Lots of googling (all which tell me the same thing to try, as above).
- Resetting Visual Studio environment settings to default.
- Exporting settings from my working laptop and importing on my PC.
- Creating a few Test projects to see if the problem was project specific (it wasn't, same thing happened on the test projects).
- Removed VS and re-installed.

Comment: Edit and Continue isn't the same thing as keeping IIS Express running, but somehow the setting seems to affect it. From what I've read and experienced, it need to be *off* for some reason for IIS Express to stay running. But YMMV.

Comment: Thanks @MattiVirkkunen - appreciate the response, just tried that and no luck on that one